# Change data on gridview row click

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net

I have two DB tables `Table1` and `Table2`

I am displaying the data of `Table1` using a `gridview`. I want to show the data of `table2` in another `gridview` when a user clicks on a row on `gridview1` i.e I want to change the data in `gridview2` when the user clicks on a row on `gridview1` . Both the tables are related using `PersonID`.

I am using windowsforms not ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also call Detail record from First Datagrid's "dataGridView1_SelectionChanged" Event like,

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int PersonID=Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["PersonID"].ToString());
        //Pass PersonID to Parameter and Get detail list

    }
```

Comment: i am trying your code i get an error "Column name not found" the column is there.

Comment: Please Replace Cells["PersonID"] into Cells[<<Your Column Name(Column index)>>]
Column Index like 0,1,2 what ever your Personid Column's Index.
If you getting error then please add your code and i will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle RowEvent event (or something like that). That way you may get value of `PersonID` (if it is bounded with DataGridView1) and use that value to fetch result from another table.

```
private void dataGridView1_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
 //Assume that the first column represents PersonID
 var firstCellValue = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value; 
 if (firstCellValue != null)
   {
      string sql="select * from Table2 where PersonID=@PersonID";
      ....
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@PersonID",SqlDbType.VarChar,20).Value=firstCellValue;
      ....
   }
}
```

Comment: what does this line do?? `cmd.Parameters.Add("@PersonID",SqlDbType.VarChar,20).Value=firstCellValue;`

Comment: @SunnyBhattacharjee - It is parameterized query and that statement create and assign parameter value.